# nested if-statement to change suffix

Tags: ms-access

pls give me the SQL to copy and paste in order to make an nested if statement that meets the following 3 conditons. Thank you very much in advance:

1. where if the field “Activity Number” doesn’t contain the character  "/”  e.g  ”1-100ZUOM1”,  then add a suffix ”/1”  e.g. ”1-100ZUOM1/1”
2. if it already does contain a suffix like ”/1”  e.g. ”1-100ZUOM1/1”, then change the last character to “2” e.g.  ”1-100ZUOM1/2”
3. if it already does contain a suffix like ”/2”  e.g. ”1-100ZUOM1/2”, then change the last character to “3” e.g.  ”1-100ZUOM1/3”

   INSERT INTO tbl_All_workorders ( [Activity Number] )
   SELECT AW.[Activity Number]
   FROM tbl_All_workorders AS AW;

Comment: Do you know how to do one of these?

Comment: is this homework? if so, then you should tag it as homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: Try using `SWITCH`. Also `pls give me the SQL` is very close to [plz send teh codez](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19780#19780) which is not something you want

Answer (score 0):

Consider altering your design so that Activity Number is stored split into two columns so that the suffix appears in its own integer column. This way, your SQL updates will be far easier to maintain and the Activity Number can be easily concatenated for display, possibly using a VIEW.